# Java. Collision detection

Tags: java, libgdx

I write a simple collision detection using rectangles. I've to check overlapping in render method. Could you tell me what's faster the first way:

```
render()
    {
        Rectangle playerRectangle = new Rectangle(
                        playerTransformComponent.x,
                        playerTransformComponent.y,
                        playerDimensionsComponent.width,
                        playerDimensionsComponent.height);
                for(Rectangle block : blocksList){
                  //check collision
                 }
    }
```

Or the second way:

```
Rectangle playerRectangle = new Rectangle();
render()
{
    playerRectangle.x = playerTransformComponent.x;
    playerRectangle.y = playerTransformComponent.y;
    playerRectangle.width = playerDimensionsComponent.width;
    playerRectangle.height = playerDimensionsComponent.height;
    for(Rectangle block : blocksList){
              //check collision
             }
}
```

Comment: What will take time is *inside* the for loop,  If you're concerned about performance you need to investigate *collision detection algorithms*, not worry about the creation of a single object.

Comment: [You've got the horses: race them](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: One of efficient ways is to use dinamic AABB tree. You can surf web for more information. Speed depends on implementation of your 'check collision' loop

Comment: you must be aware of the fact that render is called on an average 55 times per second(this may vary but point is it will be called again and again) so making an object of rectangle inside the render will create a new object 55 times per second which in turn will call for garbage collection and your game will have a lag, ur second approach is better than first one

Comment: Why is it important? You'd do just as well asking us which of the two would look better printed, framed and hung above the fireplace in your lounge room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `render()` function is a loop, so the first way is obviously wrong - you create an object every frame - it's a loss of everything.

The second way is definitely faster.
I hope it helps!
staticcasty